# How do you view pubsub feeds in admin console of Openfire?

Tags: admin, feed, publish-subscribe, openfire

Can you view pubsub feeds that are active inside Openfire? I am creating them fine (I think) on the iphone. But I usually look inside Openfire to see if I'm right. I can easily see all group chat sessions, just can't find how to view pubsubs in the admin console. Is there a plugin that I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such plugin or admin interface for pubsub in Openfire.  It is already logged in [Jira](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/OF-35).